# SFDX: How to change org's alias?

Tags: salesforcedx

I have an org connected in `sfdx` with an alias that I would like to change.

I don't see an `alias` key in the corresponding `~/.sfdx/org.json` file. I also don't see anything mentioned about this on the [org commands documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm#cli_reference_force_org).

Is there a way to do this via `sfdx-cli` without connecting to or creating the org again?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use force:alias:set:

```
sfdx force:alias:set newAlias=username@domain.com
```

The original alias is automatically removed/renamed with this command.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I looked at the alias commands but wasn't aware that this scenario is actually an alias to a username and not an org.

Comment: As of CLI version 7.75.0 using the "sfdx force:alias:set" command doesn't change the alias that is shown when you do a "sfdx force:org:list". At least not for me.

Comment: @rStrunk Thanks for the comment. I've brought this to the attention of the DX team. I'll update this answer when I get a response.

Comment: Did this answer change to update the new syntax or am I just literally insane?

Comment: @Shane `force:alias:set`, here, is the old command (still apparently works). You'll want to use the new `alias:set`, which appears to fix the problem with the old command.

Comment: Just tested it here (I'm using `sfdx-cli/7.101.0 darwin-x64 node-v14.9.0` version) and both commands (`force:alias:set` and `alias:set`) have created a new entry in my `~/.sfdx/alias.json` file.
`force:org:list` only shows the first entry so the added entry doesn't appear.
I solved the issue editing `~/.sfdx/alias.json` file directly.

Comment: Doesn't this change the **username** alias? What about the **org** alias? (e.g. "vscodeOrg")

Comment: @Saulo Hmm, might be a bug. Have you reported it to the DX team?

Comment: @jbyrd The org itself does not have an alias in DX. The listed alias is for the user. In most scratch org setups, this is synonymous, as you normally have one user in the org you work with, and you can call your alias anything you want, even `vscodeOrg`, but it's still just an alias to a user (note: this means you shouldn't log in to the same org with different users, as you'll create a lot of conflicts in your source push/pulls).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if the spec changed for `sfdx force:alias:set` but the command that worked for me involved specifying the username, as follows:

```
sfdx force:alias:set my-new-alias=foo-0rjdhesx8atr@example.com
```

Then the results of `sfdx force:org:list` is as follows:

```
 ALIAS        USERNAME                       ORG ID              EXPIRATION DATE
  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ───────────────
  my-new-alias  foo-0rjdhesx8atr@example.com  00D21000000HTDoXXO  2020-10-21
```

Comment: This worked . thanks

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the alias commands have moved from being under the force namespace to being in their own namespace.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_alias_set.htm

```
sfdx alias:set new-alias=login@example.com
```

Comment: Good catch.  `sfdx force:alias` does automatically map to `sfdx alias`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to directly edit ~/.sfdx/alias.json

Comment: This was the easiest, I do not know how many hours I have spent trying to remove unnecessary environments. thank you.

Comment: This was the easiest option. Running the "alias:set" was successful, but it never updated the alias until the entry was removed from the alias.json file. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had to also do `sfdx alias:unset blah` to remove an alias I didn't want to have in my life

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick update. If you're using a new recommended version of Salesforce CLI (`sf` commands instead of `sfdx`), use the [`sf alias set`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_alias_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_alias_set_unified) command:

> Set an alias for a scratch org username:
>
> `sf alias set my-scratch-org=test-sadbiytjsupn@example.com`
>
> Set **multiple aliases** with a single command:
>
> `sf alias set my-scratch-org=test-sadbiytjsupn@example.com my-other-scratch-org=test-ss0xut7txzxf@example.com`
>
> Set an alias that **contains spaces**:
>
> `sf alias set my-alias='alias with spaces'`
>
> Set a single alias **without using an equal sign**:
>
> `sf alias set my-scratch-org test-ss0xut7txzxf@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

In bash, using the support of jq, I set up a function like below ***NOTE**** the below function is pointing to "nonScratchOrgs" so it would need to be tweaked if we are looking to change aliases for scratch orgs as well:

```
dx-alias-replace-by-name() {
    
    echo What is the **OLD** alias name you would like to replace?
    read OLD_ALIAS
    echo What is the **NEW** alias name you would like to set?
    read NEW_ALIAS
    org_list=$(sfdx force:org:list --json)
    ORIGINAL_USERNAME=$(echo $org_list | jq --arg alias $oldalias -r '.result.nonScratchOrgs[] | select(.alias == $alias )' | jq -r '.username')
    echo sfdx alias:set $NEW_ALIAS=$ORIGINAL_USERNAME --json
    time sfdx alias:set $NEW_ALIAS=$ORIGINAL_USERNAME --json

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> sfdx alias:unset aliasvalue

as Eugene mentioned,This is the right way.

Setting an empty alias now marks the value as undefined and causes issue.